# How to persist a JsonNode object in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, jackson, morphia

I have a domain object which is being created fine from a POST method body by jackson.

```
@Entity("payloads")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Payload{
    @Id
    String payloadId;

    JsonNode data;
}
```

But when I try to persist this in mongodb I am getting the following error -

*org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory.*

I understand that instead of using JsonNode, I could create a class for *data* and either embed or reference it in *payloads* collection. But my problem is the structure of *data* is dynamic and I just want to save the Json data in mongo.

Is there anyway I could achieve this?

Comment: If you have the json you can use directly the driver to save it. Maybe is a simpler solution than use morphia:
`Document d = new Document("_id", payloadId).append("data", Document.parse(jsonString)); dbCollection.insertOne(d);`

Comment: The collection is Payloads. I have the json for one of the fields of the collection. Can I embed a document into another document using java driver.

Comment: You mean to have something like?: `{_id:xxx, data:{json}}`. This is what you'll get with the example above. Or you mean something flat like  `{_id:xxx, fields in the json here...}` ?

Comment: It is what you mentioned first. But my actual payload document would contain other fields in addition to id. `{_id:xxx, field1: {..}, field2: {..}, data:{json}}`

Comment: Yes, you would be able to add as many fields as you want: `new Document("_id", payloadId).append("data", Document.parse(jsonString)).append("field1":X).append("field2":Y); `

Comment: Sounds helpful. Il explore this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I dont want to work on a document level. Assume this class is actually a field in another class, the object of which im trying to insert. I cant possibly create a document and start appending every field manually. I'm using Java Driver's POJO support, but its not working for JsonNode. Please take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368001/inserting-a-pojo-with-a-jsonnode-field-into-mongodb-using-java-driver