# Inserting a POJO with a JsonNode field into MongoDB using Java driver

Tags: json, mongodb, jackson, mongo-java-driver

Im using Mongo Java driver 3.7

This is my POJO(with getters and setters) -

```
public class Sample{
    public int field1;
    public JsonNode field2;
}
```

Im using the below code to insert an object of Sample into MongoDB.

```
MongoCollection<Sample> myCollection = database.getCollection("myCollection",Sample.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Sample obj = new Sample();
    obj.setField1(1);
    String sampleJSON = "{ \"key\": \"value\" }";
    obj.setField2(mapper.readTree(sample));

myCollection.insertOne(obj);
```

Seen Output: (**JsonNode field is empty**)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afbff8a8f621e1e328a8c4e"),
    "field1" : 1
    "field2" : [
                 [ ]
               ],
}
```

Note:
In debug mode, it is clear that the JsonNode is created with proper data. But insert is misbehaving.
I guess I'm missing something here. Any leads appreciated.

**Update:**
I tried writing a custom codec for JsonNode class, but it is never being used by mongo. This is my codec code -

```
@Slf4j
public class JsonNodeCodec implements CollectibleCodec<JsonNode> {
    @Inject
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public JsonNode generateIdIfAbsentFromDocument(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean documentHasId(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public BsonValue getDocumentId(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode decode(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
        String task = reader.readString();
        JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(task);
        return node;
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(BsonWriter writer, JsonNode jsonNode, EncoderContext encoderContext) {
        writer.writeString(jsonNode.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<JsonNode> getEncoderClass() {
        return JsonNode.class;
    }
}
```

And I'm registering the codec like this -

```
Codec<JsonNode> jsonNodeCodec = new JsonNodeCodec();
CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(com.mongodb.MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
            CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(jsonNodeCodec),
            CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build())
    );
```

PS: Other codecs registered for custom POJOs are working fine. But this codec is never being used to encode/decode JSON objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue here and resolved using ObjectMapper.

Use below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper =   new ObjectMapper();
Map inputMap        =   mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, Map.class);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add custom converters to convert JsonNode object to org.bson.Document and vice-versa. Keep your POJOs/Document classes as it is with JsonNode fields. If using spring :

```
@Bean
public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    converters.add(JsonNodeToDocumentConverter.INSTANCE);
    converters.add(DocumentToJsonNodeConverter.INSTANCE);
    return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
}

@WritingConverter
enum JsonNodeToDocumentConverter implements Converter<JsonNode, Document> {
    INSTANCE;

    public Document convert(JsonNode source) {
        if(source == null)
            return null;

        return Document.parse(source.toString());
    }
}

@ReadingConverter
enum DocumentToJsonNodeConverter implements Converter<Document, JsonNode> {
    INSTANCE;

    public JsonNode convert(Document source) {
        if(source == null)
            return null;

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return mapper.readTree(source.toJson());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to parse DbObject to JsonNode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this just add two more converters to list existing default converters? Or this replaces all converters with two total converters?

Comment: Will add two more, Default constructor is MongoCustomConversions() {
        this(Collections.emptyList());
    }

Comment: Why you use singletons for converters?